# Unable to login Spring Security - always redirects me back to login page

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Could you please advise what is wrong in configuration. I can't login with correct credentials, it always redirects me back to login page (code 302). When type http://localhost:8080 - Spring Security redirects to /login, after form submitting redirects back to /login.

```
protected void configure (AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
    builder.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("{noop}12345").roles("USER");
}

protected void configure (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll().defaultSuccessUrl("/start.html").loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateMe");
```

```
@GetMapping("/login")
    public String showLogin () {
        return "index";
    }

    @PostMapping("/authenticateMe")
    public String login () {
        return "start";
    }
```

```
<body>

  <form method="post" th:action="@{/authenticateMe}"  class="login">
    <p>
        <label th:for="username">Username: </label>
        <input type="text" th:name="username" id="username"/>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label th:for="password">Password: </label>
        <input type="password" th:name="password" id="password"/>
    </p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overriding the url that processes the login attempt. Your code

```
@PostMapping("/authenticateMe")
public String login () {
    return "start";
}
```

Is responding to the login request, but not actually doing any processing of the login information (e.g. setting the Authentication object on the SecurityContext). You've configured an authentication manager, so remove the code from your controller and that should allow your authentication to be processed correctly.

Comment: I removed this method (/authenticateMe) from Controller, also in html I put <form method="post" th:action="@{/authenticateMe}" and it lets me in from second attempt. First attempt leads me to localhost:8080/authenticateMe (which redirects me back to login page) and only then I fill in the form and it lets me to START page.

Answer (score 0):

The path which returns login form, on same url login form should be submitted so that spring can validate input credentials and permit the access.
In your case, login form is returned on /login but form is getting submitted to authenticateMe which is why spring security can not authenticate it and is redirecting to login form again.

You can change form action to /login and spring will take care of redirecting to /start as you have registered it as success handler

Comment: Thank you. I will try. However I think I have tried this option..

Answer (score 0):

Removing `loginProcessingUrl()` should work.